# "Not to be used directly - use inside QueryOver expression" when using a generic list

Tags: c#, linq, fluent-nhibernate

What I'm trying to achieve is a search query modification based on some additional parameters. I have a list of upper limits for products. If a limit parameter is set for a product it should use it as the upper limit. If it isn't set it will use the product current value as the upper limit (so that it will allways pass).

The code looks like this:

```
subquery.WhereRestrictionOn(p => p.SomeNumberValue).IsNotNull().IsBetween(0).And(
  Projections.Conditional(
    Restrictions.On(() => alias.ProductId).IsIn(_limits),
    Projections.Property<SearchItems>(x => _limits.Where(y => y.ProductID == x.ProductId).FirstOrDefault().NewUpperLimit),
    Projections.Property<SearchItems>(p => p.SomeNumberValue)
  )
);
```

Where:

- _limits is a generic list of product limitations, taken from a database view
- SearchItems is a view that contains products, also taken from a database view

When I launch this it throws an Exception: **Not to be used directly - use inside QueryOver expression**.

I'm not sure I quite understand the problem, but...
My question is: How to point nHibernate classes like Projections to a value stored somewhere in a generic List of CustomObjects?

Comment: `_limits` is a list in memory? How could it create SQL from `_limits.Where(y => y.ProductID == x.ProductId) ...`? `Projections.Property` expects a property being chosen in a lambda expression, like `x => x.Name`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Projections.Property` expects a property being chosen in a lambda expression, like `p => p.SomeNumberValue`.

When `_limits` comes from a view, you should probably join the view in the query. Lists as arguments in queries could be a problem anyway, because the items are passed to the database as separate parameters, and there is a limit for the number of parameters.